# An syntaxError: invalid syntax at the line of else operator in the loop

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Sorry in advance for posting such a long piece of code, I shortened it as far as possible, but I think that the problem can be connected to the incorrect positioning of lines in a long loop so I see it necessary to illustrate it until the place where the error arises.

In the 10th line from the end (marked by "# Error arises here (!)") at the line of the "else" operator, I get an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". My initial intuition was that an error can be connected to improper positioning of the operator, but the text of the error doesn't seem to say so (i would expect "IndentationError: unexpected indent" error then) and it seems to me that "else" operator is positioned correctly.

Thank you.

```
if (Test_set.loc[n, '4_signals'] == 1):

 if (Portfolio_1_4_Date_sell < pd.Timestamp(Test_set.loc[n, 'feedTimestamp'])):

   try: 
        SP1500selldate_2 = n_short
        SP1500sellprice_2 = SP1500DailyReturns.loc[SP1500selldate_2, 'S&P 1500 SUPER COMPOSITE'] 
   except KeyError:
     try:
       SP1500buydate_2 = SP1500buydate_2 - pd.Timedelta("1 day") 

     except KeyError:
       SP1500buydate_2 = SP1500buydate_2 - pd.Timedelta("2 days") 
   
   Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_2_4'] = Portfolio_2_4
  
   try: 
        SP1500selldate_3 = n_short
        SP1500sellprice_3 = SP1500DailyReturns.loc[SP1500selldate_3, 'S&P 1500 SUPER COMPOSITE - PRICE INDEX']

   except KeyError:
     try:
       SP1500buydate_3 = SP1500buydate_3 - pd.Timedelta("1 day") 

     except KeyError:
       SP1500buydate_3 = SP1500buydate_3 - pd.Timedelta("2 days")  
   
   Portfolio_3_4 = Portfolio_3_4 * SP1500sellprice_3 / SP1500buyprice_3
   SP1500buydate_3_SP1500 = n_short
   Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_3_4'] = Portfolio_3_4

 else:
   Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_1_4_allocation'] = 'Portfolio 1 is already allocated!'
   Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_1_4'] = Portfolio_1_4
     
   try: 
        SP1500selldate_3 = n_short
        SP1500sellprice_3 = SP1500DailyReturns.loc[SP1500selldate_3, 'S&P 1500 SUPER COMPOSITE - PRICE INDEX']

   except KeyError:
     try:
       SP1500buydate_3 = SP1500buydate_3 - pd.Timedelta("1 day") 
       SP1500buydate_3_str = SP1500buydate_3.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

     except KeyError:
       SP1500buydate_3 = SP1500buydate_3 - pd.Timedelta("2 days") 
       SP1500buydate_3_str = SP1500buydate_3.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

           
   Portfolio_3_4 = Portfolio_3_4 * SP1500sellprice_3 / SP1500buyprice_3
   SP1500buydate_3_SP1500 = n_short
   Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_3_4'] = Portfolio_3_4

   else:    # Error arises here (!)
     Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_2_4_allocation'] = 'Portfolio 1 and 2 are already allocated!'
     Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_2_4'] = Portfolio_2_4
     if (Portfolio_3_4_Date_sell < pd.Timestamp(Test_set.loc[n, 'feedTimestamp'])):
       Portfolio_3_4 = Portfolio_3_4 * Test_set.loc[n, 'Cumulative stock Returns over the 30 days after transaction  (22 working days)'] 
       Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_3_4'] = Portfolio_3_4
       Portfolio_3_4_Date_sell = Date_Buy + pd.Timedelta("30 days")
     else:
       Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_3_4_allocation'] = 'Portfolio 1, 2 and 3 are already allocated!'
       Test_set.loc[n, 'Portfolio_3_4'] = Portfolio_3_3
```

Comment: `else` can't be at the same indentation level as the preceding code.

Comment: Also, please note that you should always include the complete error message in you question (and not some more or less vague description of it). For syntax errors, a few lines before and after the line where the error happens is enough, we don't need the whole code.

Comment: Your code is missing a `'` please add it otherwise it is difficult to look at with the syntax highlighing,

Comment: Thank you, I added the ', so the code is shown correctly currently. The whole text of error is   (File "<ipython-input-77-0e5b1accf48f>", line 116
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax).

Comment: that `else` is at the same level as the block text above. But an else must be part of an `if` clause and that means the text above will be indented. __Use 4 spaces for each indented block__. There is a reason for this. Its hard to spot where the indented blocks are when you just use one or two. Scientists have proven that there are enough spaces to last over a hundred years - and they are non polluting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying

```py
try:
    #something
except KeyError:
    #something
else:
    #something
```

then there cannot be anything in between them at the indentation level of the `try`.
Your code is something like

```py
try:
    #something
except KeyError:
    #something
#something
else:
    #something
```

which is why interpreter is reporting a syntax error.